# Submit button doesn't work on enter

Tags: html, forms, submit

I have several "submit" inputs on my form (this is caused by a framework I'm using), so to control what button is actually activated on "Enter" (as well as by "Go" button of Android keyboard), I have added this markup:

```
<input type="submit" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:-100px;"
onclick="$('#DefaultButton').click();return false;" />
```

I'm placing it in the very beginning, so that it's first in order, but still inside of the form.
This works great in one of my applications, but not working at all in the other!

Even more suprising is that in that other application, there is a case when there is 1 single submit, so it should be working as the default without any additional work, but it never worked. Even when I add this hidden submit - it doesn't work neither. I have checked via javascript the count of submits on the page - and it have shown me 2: one is the one visible to user, the other is this one I'm adding.

Ok, I did javascript to handle keypress, it's working, but I don't like this aproach - I would prefer the natural way, when first submit acts as the default button.

Also, I have checked on mobile - I thought there will be problem that "Go" button will not work - but it is working. So it's not working in desktop browser only.

What can be the problem here? Is my submit missing any attribute?

I can't post the whole page, cause it's huge, here is a simplified markup of that "real" submit button (it is generated by the framework):

```
<input onclick="*Ajax javascript*; return false;" type="submit"
name="DefaultButton" value="Continue" id="DefaultButton" tabindex="17"
class="Button" />
```

Here is also the form tag (also generated by the framework):

```
<form method="post" action="Signup.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();"
id="WebForm1" name="WebForm1">
```

UPDATE. I'd like to note again, that I made it working via handling onkeypress for keyCode == 13, I was just wondering why normal submit button doesn't react on Enter, as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$('#DefaultButton').trigger("click");
```

Remove the `javascript:` from `onsubmit`:

```
onsubmit="return WebForm_OnSubmit();"
```

Comment: The `javascript:` is harmless but does not belong there anyway

Comment: I tried changing to trigger('click'), but that didn't work, unfortunately. I can't remove onsubmit because it's generated by the framework. The function contains validation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to submit in a form field on enter

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13 && e.target.type=="text") {
    if (WebForm_OnSubmit()) $("WebForm1").submit();
  }
});
```

You can remove all the submit buttons too if you want

```
$("input[type='submit']").remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your input and button into **form tags** and the script directly in your html document. Change the onclick value with the function you want to use. The script in the html will tell the form to submit when the user hits enter or press the submit button.

```
 <form id="Form-v2" action="#">

<input type="text" name="search_field"  placeholder="Enter a movie" value="" 
id="search_field" title="Enter a movie here" class="blink search-field"  />
<input type="submit" value="GO!" class="search-button" />       
 </form>

    <script>
    //submit the form
    $( "#Form-v2" ).submit(function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
    });
         </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely due to a **server-side implementation arrangement issue** since the form is submitted with submit button click expectation when this HTML is coded, the server-side is likely trying to listen to a `$_POST["submit"]` value, but then since the Enter key bypassed the need of pressing the button, this omits the submit value and the form will not work with the server code (it simply gets ignored).

This also explains the `onkeypress` (kinda dirty) fix works since you bind the keypress to the submit button action again via the native HTML form submit support, which is just equivalent to pressing the first declared submit button on-page.

The reason I say the `onkeypress` is a dirty fix means that existing compatible accessibility tools or future-proof considerations would not be suitable for the code to react to 1 key only, given the chance for all tools to match this particular code.

You can consider the proper fix to assign a `form_id` in URL query `?form_id=123` or a hidden variable pre-filled by the server `<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="123">` to let you identify it is the form that the server is waiting for. Keep the `form_id` in Session, and this would work even when the user submits the form using Enter or mouseclick.